# Get [object Object] error when Uploading a file (image or audio) to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, file-upload

I'm not sure why I'm getting `[object Object]` error when uploading a file to Firebase. I know I'm getting the URI of the image right. I also tried the put method and got the same error. Any help?

```js
const filename = 'images/test.jpg'; //+ new Date() + image + '.jpg';

const uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename).putString(image.uri, 'data_url');

uploadTask.on()
```

[image]

Comment: How are you logging out the error?

Comment: it is displayed on the simulator. here is an image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YYkr.png

Comment: Are you able to apply a call to `JSON.stringify` and pass the error in, so that you can read it?